# Retrieve the entire file content as string instead of word by word - Linux command

Tags: unix, cat, npm-scripts

I'm trying to reference .sql file in an npm script.

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
   ...,
   "rls:on": "npm run typeorm query $(cat src/policies/enable-rls.sql)"
}
```

**enable-rls.sql**

```
 ALTER TABLE folder ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

On running the command above I get the following error:

> `QueryFailedError: unterminated quoted string at or near "ALTER"`

Because the sql read from the file retrieved as single words:

```
"ALTER" "TABLE" "folder" "ENABLE" "ROW" "LEVEL" "SECURITY;"
```

Instead of full text:

```
"ALTER TABLE folder ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;"
```

What is the command to read the qsl as full text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encase the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) part, i.e. `$(...)`, in JSON escaped double quotes `\"...\"`

For instance change your npm script to the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "rls:on": "npm run typeorm query \"$(cat src/policies/enable-rls.sql)\""
                                   ^^                                  ^^
}
```